# Programmatically move the cursor to a desired location on the screen

Tags: front-end

Is it possible to set/move the mouse pointer's location directly from *Mathematica* without using external tools like `Run["xdotool mousemove x y"]`?

Comment: If an interactive application like Mathematica did that, I would consider it a bug... Anyway, I don't think it's possible from _within_ Mathematica.

Comment: You don't mean setting the current insertion point or selection?

Comment: not the selection inside Mathematica. Just moving the mouse pointer anywhere inside the screen

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
Needs["JLink`"]
ReinstallJava[]
robotclass=JavaNew["java.awt.Robot"]
robotclass@mouseMove[#,300]&/@Range@900;
```

Comment: Impressive .. :)

Comment: Second that, impressive indeed, +1.

Comment: +1 Great ;-) `Table[robotclass@mouseMove[Round[300 (Cos[x] + 1)], Round[100 (Sin[2 x] + 1)]], {x,  0, 2 Pi, .001}];`

Comment: Excellent - that seems like a prime candidate for causing some desktop mischief ;-)

Comment: Very nice Andreas. +1. Java rules!

Comment: Impressive?? That's scary...

Comment: Impressive + Thanks !

Comment: Linking to Java is not considered using an external tool?  Interesting....

Comment: @John: No, it's not. a) in the example of the o/p xdotool would be an external tool/application/program that you'd need to call. b) JLink is part of M, and WRI's official position is that this makes all of Java part of M (same with NETLink and .Net), as indicated by marketing materials. c) you ARE actually writing this in M. My code above is NOT Java code, it's M code. It just LOOKs like Java code (and that's a smart design choice of JLink/NETLink), but it isn't. These are all M symbols, it's M syntax, it runs from the M f/e, and it is executed/"scripted" through the kernel.