# Cursor Position / Insertion Point

Tags: front-end, keyboard

Is there a way to access (or even set) the **cursor** position in a Notebook?

(By **Cursor** I refer to the keyboard input postion, or "Insertion Point". For the Mouse we have `CurrentValue["MousePosition"]` or just `MousePosition[]`)

Note that calling external tools is only the seconds best option for me.
See [Programmatically move the cursor to a desired location on the screen](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9332/programmatically-move-the-cursor-to-a-desired-location-on-the-screen?rq=1) (which is also about the mouse)

Comment: One thing that makes this question difficult to answer is lack of specification of the expected position datum -- should it be X number of Cells into the Notebook, or a certain number of characters into the expression returned by `NotebookGet`, or...?

Comment: You are right. I'm sure MMA has such a specification internally, but maybe it cannot be accessed!? So I was refering to that -unknown- internal spec.

Comment: Fair enough.  Let me ask the question in a different way:  what would you *do* with this internal spec if you had it?  There is apparently no way to feed it to `SelectionMove`.  What kind of interaction are you envisioning?

Comment: The simplest application is just **saving** the insertion point and setting it back later!

Comment: That's just the problem though; I don't know if any way to say "move cursor to point X" but only "move cursor X units of type Y in direction Z."  Perhaps you could use some marker and then do a text search for that.  I don't think there are many tools provided for this kind of thing; it's typically much easier to work with the Notebook expression than with the GUI Notebook itself.

Comment: The cursor position is tracked in the ``Devceloper`CellInformation``. Have a look at my implementation of the code highlighter in [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1315/customizing-syntax-highlighting-for-private-cell-styles/1320#1320) to see how it can be practically used.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin
1. Cannot find your code 
2. Can `CellInformation` be used to SET something?

Comment: Have a look at http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/7246/ to learn about tagging and **moving to** tagged cells; as well as CellIDs (not the same as `CellSerialNumber` from `CellInformation`).

Answer (score 5):

Setting the position may be easier than retrieving it as there exists [`SelectionMove`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SelectionMove.html).

No record of the insertion point appears in the output of [`NotebookGet`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NotebookGet.html).  At the moment the best I can think of is to use [`NotebookWrite`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NotebookWrite.html) to insert a unique token and then search the expression returned by `NotebookGet` for this token, but this changes the target Notebook.

Perhaps if you described your application I would be able to provide other suggestions.

Comment: unique token... VERY good point!

Comment: Aha, from experimenting with `SelectionMove` I come to the conclusion that a "Selection" can also be empty and then just represents the Insertion point. This is not at all evident from the naming of that function! (this happens e.g. on `SelectionMove[nb, Next, Character]`

Comment: @NoEscape, sorry, I guess should have said that in my answer.

Comment: With `Developer\`CellInformation` you get the cursor position within the selected cell, and the selected cell serial number whatever that means