# How to execute this code on startup?

Tags: front-end, notebooks, interface

Every time I open a new notebook I have to manually evaluate this [code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/125021/make-cursor-stay-in-input-cell) in that notebook. In order order to stop my cursor moving to a new cell.

How would I automate this?
I would love this functionality to auto-load on startup.

I have tried putting it in a `file.m` file and adding a `Get["/path/to/file.m"]` line, to my `FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory , "Kernel", "init.m"}]`. Unfortunately this does not work. As it seems to need to be evaluated in the `SelectedNotebook[]` to work.

Here is the code by @Kuba

```
With[
  { nb := EvaluationNotebook[]
  , c := EvaluationCell[]
  }
, With[
    { cv := CurrentValue[nb, {"TaggingRules", "LastCursorPosition"}]
    , pos := FrontEndExecute@FrontEnd`UndocumentedGetSelectionPacket[nb]
    }
  , With[
      { savePosition := (
          cv = If[MemberQ[pos, "CharacterRange" -> _], Last["CharacterRange" /. pos], False]
        )
      }
    , SetOptions[nb
      , CellEventActions :> {
          {"MenuCommand", "HandleShiftReturn"} :> savePosition
        , {"MenuCommand", "EvaluateCells"} :> savePosition
        , PassEventsDown -> True
        }
      , CellEpilog :>  If[
          IntegerQ[cv]
        , SelectionMove[c, Before, CellContents]
        ; SelectionMove[nb, Next, Character, cv]
        ; cv = False
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a stylesheet version that mimics Kuba's code:

```
With[{cv := CurrentValue[EvaluationCell[], {TaggingRules, "LastCursorPosition"}]},
    SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[],
        StyleDefinitions -> Notebook[
            {
            Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions->"Default.nb"]],
            Cell[StyleData["Input"],
                CellEventActions -> {
                    {"MenuCommand","HandleShiftReturn"} :> Set[
                        cv,
                        Replace[
                            Lookup[
                                Developer`CellInformation @ EvaluationCell[],
                                "CursorPosition"
                            ],
                            {
                                {_, i_} -> i,
                                _ -> False
                            }
                        ]
                    ],
                    PassEventsDown->True
                },
                CellEpilog :> Replace[cv,
                    i_Integer :> (
                        SelectionMove[EvaluationCell[], Before, CellContents];
                        SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], Next, Character, i];
                        cv = False
                    )
                ],
                TaggingRules -> {}
            ]
            },
            StyleDefinitions->"PrivateStylesheetFormatting.nb"
        ]
    ]
]
```

You can modify the default stylesheet to use for new notebooks, see the answers to [How to change the default Notebook stylesheet](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/132349/45431).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I followed the link and I have successfully changed my default notebook stylesheet from `Default.nb` to `DefaultModified.nb`. I am confused. Where do I put your code? Do I paste it somewhere inside `DefaultModified.nb`?

Comment: @ConorCosnett If you have a stylesheet that you want to modify to include the above styles, you can open a new notebook and run the above code in the notebook. Then, edit the notebook stylesheet, copy the "Input" style, and paste it into the stylesheet you want to modify.

Answer (score 3):

For future generations, this is how you do it. Place this in your `init.m`:

```
If[$Notebooks,
AppendTo[CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, {CodeAssistOptions, "IncludedCompletions"}], "Blacklisted"];
Begin["CursorSave`"];
SaveCursorPosition[] := ( 
    $LastNotebookObject = EvaluationNotebook[];
    $LastCellObject = First @ SelectedCells[$LastNotebookObject];
    $LastCellCursorPosition = First @ Lookup[
        Developer`CellInformation[EvaluationCell[]], 
        "CursorPosition"
    ];
);
RestoreCursorPosition[] := (
    SelectionMove[$LastCellObject, Before, CellContents];
    SelectionMove[$LastNotebookObject, Next, Character, $LastCellCursorPosition];
);
SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, FrontEndEventActions -> {{"MenuCommand", "HandleShiftReturn"} :> 
    (SaveCursorPosition[]; FrontEndTokenExecute["EvaluateCells"]; RestoreCursorPosition[])}];
End[];
];
```