# Keyboard shortcut for evaluating the current cell while keeping the cursor in the cell

Tags: front-end

[Make cursor stay in input cell](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/125021) provides a function for keeping the cursor in a cell after it was evaluated. I tried adding that function directly into KeyEventTranslations.tr to create a keyboard shortcut but that led to Mathematica sending an error when loading. I tried wrapping it in KernelExecute but that did not work. I would also like to modify shift plus enter to remove the setting from the function in the link when I want the standard way of evaluating a cell.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following adds a new menu item "Evaluate Cells (Keep Selection)" with shortcut "Alt+Shift+Return" that keeps the cursor where it is:

```
FrontEndExecute@FrontEnd`AddMenuCommands[
    If[$OperatingSystem == "Windows", "EvaluateCells", "HandleShiftReturn"], {
      MenuItem["Evaluate Cells (Keep Selection)",
        KernelExecute@evaluateKeepSelection[],
        System`MenuKey[
          "Return",
          System`Modifiers -> {"Shift", "Option"}
          ],
        System`MenuEvaluator -> Automatic
        ]}]
 
evaluateKeepSelection[] := 
 With[{nb := EvaluationNotebook[], c := EvaluationCell[]}, 
  With[{cv := 
     CurrentValue[nb, {"TaggingRules", "LastCursorPosition"}], 
    pos := FrontEndExecute@
      FrontEnd`UndocumentedGetSelectionPacket[nb]}, 
   cv = "CharacterRange" /. pos;
   FrontEndExecute@FrontEndToken["EvaluateCells"]; 
   SetOptions[nb, 
    CellEpilog :> 
     If[ListQ[cv], SelectionMove[c, Before, CellContents]; 
      SelectionMove[nb, Next, Character, First[cv]]; 
      SelectionMove[nb, After, Character]; 
      FrontEndExecute@
       Table[FrontEndToken["SelectNext"], -Subtract @@ cv];
      cv = False]]]
  ]
```

[image]

Note that this keeps the usual behavior of "Shift+Return" as it is, it just adds an additional shortcut that keeps the selection.

Comment: I do not see a menu item either on Linux with version 13.2. Maybe I could use https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/AddMenuItem/ somehow to add the menu item ? (I did not try using that function i just saw it in the past)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Can you try again? I tweaked the call to `AddMenuCommands` slightly, hopefully that makes it more robust...

Comment: @userrandrand That resource function does nothing else than call ``FrontEndExecute@FrontEnd`AddMenuCommands``, so I am a bit surprised my code didn't work for you (or MichaelE2). As I already mentioned, I tweaked the call slightly in the hopes to make the call work now

Comment: @MichaelE2 Looks like the relevant token is `"HandleShiftReturn"` instead of `"EvaluateCells"` on Linux for some reason (I assume it's the same on macOS as well). I updated the answer to include a check for the OS, and it works now for a fresh install on Ubuntu for me. Can you check again on macOS?

Comment: Success! It works. (+1)

Comment: Very nice. Thank you I will offer this answer a bounty in 2 days for the great solution.

Comment: If I want to save this for all sessions should I save it in the frontend init.m ? I have only used the kernel init.m

Comment: @userrandrand I haven't tried it myself so far, but does [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1606/how-make-addmenucommands-work-in-an-init-m) work for you?

Comment: @LukasLang thank you, it seems I had bookmarked that page in the past haha.