# How can I focus cursor at specific position?

Tags: inputfield, button

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Programmatically move the cursor to a desired location on the screen](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9332/programmatically-move-the-cursor-to-a-desired-location-on-the-screen)

I made a `Button` with the name of "Click",if we have to click on `Button`,`CreateDialog` will appear with two `InputFields` and one `Button`.

I want to focus the cursor in the first `InputField`,whenever we have to press on `Button`(Click)

```
       first = Null;
       second = Null;
       Button["Click", 
              (*Button Action Start from here*)
              (CreateDialog[Grid[{{Style["first", Bold],InputField[Dynamic[first]]},             
                                  {Style["Second", Bold],InputField[Dynamic[second]]},  
                                  {Button["Ok",DialogReturn[]],SpanFromLeft}}]]
              )(*Button Action closed here*),
             ImageSize -> {180, 60}
             ]
```

Comment: ...or this one: [Programmatically move the cursor...](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9332/89).