# Automate mouse clicks with Mathematica

Tags: java

I need to automate mouse clicks with *Mathematica*. However, a [similiar question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14151/use-mathematica-to-automate-mouse-clicks-and-or-key-presses) was closed on this forum, without any answer.

Consider the following steps:

```
 Dynamic[MousePosition[]]
```

In this first step I dynamically show the mouse position.

```
 DynamicModule[{col = Green}, EventHandler[ Style["text", FontColor -> 
 Dynamic[col]], {"MouseClicked" :> (col = col /. {Red -> Green, Green -> Red})}]]
```

In this second step I create a "clickable" text: when you click it, it changes its color between green and red.

My objective here is twofold:

**1)** automatically move the cursor position - this has already been answered [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9332/programmatically-move-the-cursor-to-a-desired-location-on-the-screen). So, following the original answer I can write

```
Needs["JLink`"];
ReinstallJava[];
robotclass = JavaNew["java.awt.Robot"];
robotclass@mouseMove[90, 196];
```

**2)** automatically click on the clickable text (and, of course, I want to see its color changing). Here is the code I'm trying to use:

```
robotclass@mousePress[InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK];
robotclass@mouseRelease[InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK];
```

Although I believe I'm using the correct functions (which belong to the Java Robot Class), I'm getting the following error message:

> Java::argx1: Method named mouseRelease defined in class java.awt.Robot was called with an incorrect number or type of arguments. The argument was InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK.

Can anybody give me a hint to solve this problem?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the raw integer value 16, but the correct J/Link syntax for the symbolic name is `` InputEvent`BUTTON1UMASK ``, so your code would look like this:

```
(* Call LoadJavaClass when needing to refer to static members. *)
LoadJavaClass["java.awt.event.InputEvent"];

robotclass@mousePress[InputEvent`BUTTON1UMASK];
robotclass@mouseRelease[InputEvent`BUTTON1UMASK];
```

Enter JLink/tutorial/CallingJavaFromMathematica#15615 into the Documentation Center to see the section of the J/Link docs that talks about how to construct this name. BUTTON1_MASK is a static member of the InputEvent class, hence the `, and the _ character needs to be converted into a U to make it a legal Mathematica symbol name.

Comment: It also works! +1

Comment: hmm wonder why this syntax didn't occur to me. @RodLm feel free to change the accepted question

Answer (score 5):

`InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK` is an attempt to get the *dot product* of `InputEvent` and `BUTTON1_MASK`, neither of which are matrices. You're using Java syntax in a Mathematica program.

I don't know what the idiomatic JLink approach is, but if you look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.awt.event.InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK) you can see that `InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK` has the integer value 16 (the `BUTTON1_MASK` is just a variable for programmer convenience -- easier to deal with than an arbitrary integer).

Comment: I've tried other sintaxes as well... for instance, instead of `InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK` I've also tried `InputEvent[BUTTON1_MASK]`, `mouseRelease["InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK"]`, 'mouseRelease[InputEvent,BUTTON1_MASK]' and so on... but nothing seems to work... By the way, you could have put a comment instead of an answer... anyway, thank you.

Comment: @RodLm for some reason i had assumed you were familiar with Java. to be clearer: the `mousePress` function expects an integer. `mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK)` works in Java because `InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK` is an integer in Java. what you do with this knowledge is something i leave to you :)

Comment: +1! It works... You only need to use `robotclass@mousePress[16]` and it works perfectly. Thanks!