# Automate Windows From Mathematica

Tags: version-10, automation

Is there a feasible way to automate Windows from Mathematica?

I'm thinking maybe with the .NETLink?
If not maybe just mouse movements or keyborad shortcuts ?

This might be a good start https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff486375(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: What tasks would you like to automate?

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30695/5478

Comment: @Kuba isn't there something more complicated like the following http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1775/web-browsing-automation-with-mathematica but for the windows api.  If you change screen size pointer movements would no longer work.