# Mathematica scripting on Microsoft Windows

Tags: windows, scripting

Is it possible to use *Mathematica* (or the *Mathematica* kernel) to interact with  Microsoft Windows, much like any macro-based scripting language that controls the keyboard/mouse, opens/closes programs remotely, manipulate window sizes, files, and folders, etc?

It seems *Mathematica* is usually used for math related engineering purposes inside the *Mathematica* notebooks, I'm interested in its symbolic programming style to create standalone applications that interact with windows (to automate repetitive tasks).

Comment: [controlling mouse with MMA](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9332/programmatically-move-the-cursor-to-a-desired-location-on-the-screen)

Answer (score 12):

I have automated a nightly backup process with Mathematica. I use a task scheduling program to run a longer version of the following .m file below with MathKernel.  Functions like `Complement`make it easy to copy new files from a working directory to a backup directory, and in general, Mathematica makes it easy to use sophisticated logic along with various file functions in backup operations. I use `$Output` to redirect the output of print statements to a date stamped processing log so I know what happened. While there is nothing special about the little piece of Mathematica code below, it illustrates some of the things I just described.  You could certainly use this approach for much more complicated kinds of processing.

```
fname="C:\\automation\\"<>"backup "<>datestamp<> ".txt";
Block[{$Output = OpenWrite[fname, FormatType -> OutputForm, TotalWidth -> Infinity]},
workingpath = "E:\\Index Calculation\\";
backuppath = "C:\\Dropbox\\Index Calculation\\";

Print[datestamp];
Print["Backing up "];
Print[workingpath<> " to " <>backuppath];

SetDirectory[backuppath]; 
backupfiles = Select[FileNames[], ! DirectoryQ[#1] &];
SetDirectory[workingpath]; 
workingfiles = Select[FileNames[], ! DirectoryQ[#1] &];
missingfiles = Complement[workingfiles, backupfiles];

If[Length[missingfiles] == 0,  Print["\nNo files missing in " <> backuppath] ];
Close[$Output]; ]
```

I simplified the code above to make it brief; "datestamp" is actually:

```
DateString[{"Year", "Month", "Day", " ", "Hour", "Minute", "Second"}]
```

To archive instead of overwrite a file that changes daily but that I'd like to keep a rolling history of, I use the following strategy:

```
If[FileExistsQ[indexname],
tag=DateString[FileDate[index <> " Index.xlsx"],{"Year","Month","Day","Hour", "Minute","Second"}];
newname = StringReplace[index<>" Index.xlsx",{".xlsx" ->" "<>tag<> ".xlsx"}];
Print["Changing index file to " <> newname];
If[!FileExistsQ[newname], RenameFile[indexname, newname];];
];
```

You can create a list of sub-directories for processing with `FileNames` and `Select` (I prefix their names with "@" if I want to keep them out of the list). With this approach, any new sub-directory you create will be automatically included.

```
SetDirectory["E:\\Index Calculation\\"];
dlist = Select[Select[FileNames[], DirectoryQ[#]&], StringTake[#,1] != "@"&];
Do[
   index = dlist[[i]];
   Print[index];
   (*do automation stuff*)
,{i, 1, Length@dlist}]
```

Although it's the final answer was simple, it took time for me to figure how to run backup.m automatically. I use VisualCron to run a .bat file containing:

```
Mathkernel -script backup.m
```

I would rather run backup.m directly, but can't get Cron to co-operate.

As Kuba says, Mathematica makes everyday programming tasks easier.

Comment: +1 I like this. Such simple/short solutions are why I like MMA :) `FileDate` may be useful too if one is expecting any updates.

Comment: @Kuba You're right. It's so useful I added an example.