# Control mouse movement and keyboard during screen recording

Tags: keyboard, video

I want to record my screen, as explained [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VideoRecord.html), and during the recording to move the mouse from point (x1,y1) on the screen to point (x2,y2), in a straight line, with some specified speed.

The software I want to record is *not* Mathematica, but some other software installed on my computer, for the purpose of instructing others how to use it.

If possible, I also want to type some text programmatically, in a "non-human" way of typing quickly without stops, without fixing typos etc.

Is it possible to do the mouse movement and the typing with Mathematica?

Or should I resort to [Automator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_macOS_components#Automator) etc. in order to simulate the instructions?

Comment: Have you tried [Robot through JLink](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9676/17)?

Comment: Never heard of it. Looks too complicated for me.. I think I will just use macOS automator.. Is there a WL function that makes a call to automator? I want to make a mouse movement and some keyboard strokes right after I start recording my screen

Comment: Sorry... Unfortunately I never touched a Mac nor do I have any knowledge on that.